CQRS handling exceptions in commands and log them properly
In my nestJS application I am using nest-cqrs. The problem I have is whenever an unhandled exception is thrown at the command handler, actual reason is not getting logged but it logs about RxJS errors which is wrong. Below is a cut down version of my code
export class CreateTenantCommand {
  constructor(public readonly createTenantDto: CreateTenantDto) {}
}

@CommandHandler(CreateTenantCommand)
export class CreateTenantCommandHandler
  implements ICommandHandler<CreateTenantCommand>
{
    ###code
    throw Error('something went wrong')
}

If I call the above command like below
const { success, message } = await this.commandBus.execute<CreateTenantCommand,DataResponseDto>(new CreateTenantCommand(createTenantDto))


the exception is caught in my global exception filter and the error logged is related to RxJS and not the actual error thrown by me.
If I change the way I called the command from my controller as below:
    const { success, message } = await this.commandBus.execute<CreateTenantCommand,DataResponseDto>(new CreateTenantCommand(createTenantDto))
    .catch((err) => {
      throw Error(err);
    });

Note that I have a catch() with execute(). If I do it this way the actual error is caught in this catch() and since I rethrow, it gets captured in global exception filter as well. However global filter exception handler again shows the wrong error related to RxJS! partial error is below

"message":"no elements in sequence","timestamp":"2024-10-22T07:46:07.466Z","path":"/tenant","method":"POST","stackTrace":"Error\n    at _super (D:\Projects\Streamline\streamline\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\util\createErrorClass.js:7:26)\n    at new EmptyErrorImpl (D:\Projects\Streamline\streamline\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\util\EmptyError.js:6:5)\n    at Object.complete (D:\Projects\Streamline\streamline\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\lastValueFrom.js:24:28)\n    at ......

What may be the problem here?
